# React Native - useState - Text Input field is not clearing the first character from state after I delete all text from input

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, textinput, react-native-textinput

My problem is that when I enter on the airline textInput for example "TEST" and when I enter the delete keyboard button, the last character stays in the state ex: "T", but in view it shows like its fully deleted. With console.log(routes) I can see that the last character T is still in the object. Below is my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `airline` state via the function `setAirline` in the `onChangeText` callback function in the `Airline` component, but you are using the internal state called `state` of this component which you are setting **after** you are setting the airline equal to `state`.

This lines of code should be the problem.

```js
onChangeText={el => {
  setAirline(state);
  setState(el);
}}
```

`airline` is never equal to `el`. Suppose the `state` is equal to `TEST`. We delete one character. `T` is removed and the `onChangeText` callback function is called and `el` is equal to `TES`, but you are calling `setAirline(state)` **before** `setState(el)`, hence in that very moment `state` is still equal to `TEST`. The airline will not be updated correctly.

If you delete everything, then the last character will never be removed from the `airline` state.

One possible solution is to just use the callback value of the function for the `airline` as well.

```js
onChangeText={el => {
  setAirline(el);
  setState(el);
}}
```

But in this case we might ask: why are we creating a new state anyway? Instead, pass the `airline` state along with its setter function to the component and use it as usual.

```js
<Airline airline={airline} setAirline={setAirline} emptyField={emptyAirline} />

xport const Airline = ({ setAirline, airline }: AirlineProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      title={getAirline + ' (optional)'}
      value={airline}
      onChangeText={el => {
        setAirline(el);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Your solution works perfect,  but the only problem I have is that when I switch the dropdown value and I comeback to the Route Fields screen, the state of airline doesn't get reset to the initial value. I have tried to do it with  the solution below, but it doesn't work. 

  `navigation.addListener(ON_SCREEN_FOCUS, () => {
    setAirline('');
  });
  navigation.addListener(ON_SCREEN_BLUR, () => {
    setAirline('');
  });`

Anyway your solution fixes my first problem so thank you very much :)

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is very well explained [here in the official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/).